# Close icon in Winter Bash profile dialog not visible when hovering

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

When hovering over the Close button in the top right of the Winter/Summer Bash 2022 dialog on your profile, it becomes entirely white:

[image]

It would be better if the close icon × would remain visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Woops, looks like we didn't override all of Stacks' default appearance! I've disabled the background on hover for this button for now. I'll come back to improve the accessibility behind it soon but that will require some fixes in Stacks (there's some CSS specificity conflicts preventing that).

Comment: Related (resulting?) issue: [X to exit hat modal blends into banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384847/335251)