# X to exit hat modal blends into banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, responsive-design, winter-bash-2022

This is the hat modal on Community's profile in dark mode. As you can see (or can you?), the X in the corner blends into the banner, potentially because of my screen size:

[image]

(Also happens in light mode.)

There should be a shadow or something so it can be visible.

Comment: Related (potentially the cause of this?): [Close icon in Winter Bash profile dialog not visible when hovering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384711/335251)

Comment: It's been fixed now. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed!

[image: there is a square shadow now]